# Is it possible to use Cassandra with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I would like to try Cassandra, but don't know how to integrate Cassandra with Node.js. When I say Node.js it is MEAN.JS or any other framework. Just let me know if there is a way?

Comment: Have you tried googling `cassandra node js`?

Comment: Yes Joe,  I had tried and it is still going on project .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow these links [datastax](https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-nodejs) and [github datastax node.js driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver)

If you are new to cassandra then you can study cassandra on [datastax](https://academy.datastax.com) for free also.
You can use this [cassandra-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-client) npm also.